# jQuery if statement broken?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a php webpage where a user enters their details into a form and after submitting two sections, named profile and images, must then appear. Here is the javascript code:

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            var registered = <?php echo $registered; ?>;
            alert(registered);
            if (registered == 'false') {

                $("#profile").hide();
                $("#images").hide();
            }
            if (registered == 'true') {

                                    alert('hello');
                $("#profile").show();
                $("#images").show();
            }

        });
```

For some reason it does not go into the if statement at all, even though the alert shows registered's value as true. What could be the problem here?

Comment: What is the value of $registered...Is it returning boolena value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var registered = <?php json_encode($registered) ?>
if(registered == true) {
    alert(registered);    
    $("#profile").hide();
    $("#images").hide();
} else {
    alert('hello');
    $("#profile").show();
    $("#images").show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up the string `'true'` with the boolean `true`. Try a version that uses booleans from start to finish instead:

```
var registered = <?= json_encode($registered) ?>;

if (registered) {
    $("#profile").hide();
    $("#images").hide();
} else {
    $("#profile").show();
    $("#images").show();
}
```

*Edit - Thanks to Jon in another comment for suggesting using `json_encode`.*

Answer (score 0):

use `JSON.parse()` Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting JavaScript object.

```
 //JSON.parse(registered);

var registered = <?php echo $registered; ?>;

        if (!(JSON.parse(registered))) {

            $("#profile").hide();
            $("#images").hide();
        }
       else {

            $("#profile").show();
            $("#images").show();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the quotes and try

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

            var registered = <?php echo $registered; ?>;
            alert(registered);
            if (registered == false) {  //Remove the quotes

                $("#profile").hide();
                $("#images").hide();
            }
            if (registered == true) {   //Remove the quotes

                                    alert('hello');
                $("#profile").show();
                $("#images").show();
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Reason in this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4fh26/).

```
var registered = true;
alert(registered == 'true'); //return false
alert(registered == 'false'); //return false
```

In JavaScript data type comparison is a bit inconsistent. So always try to compare same data-types.

so try:

```
var registered = true;
alert(registered == true); //return true
alert(registered == false); //return false
```

Change your code to:

```
if (registered) {
    alert('hello');
    $("#profile").show();
    $("#images").show();
}
else {
    $("#profile").hide();
    $("#images").hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var registered = "<?php echo $registered; ?>";
alert(registered);
if (registered == false) {

 $("#profile").hide();
 $("#images").hide();
  }
 else if (registered == true) {

   alert('hello');
  $("#profile").show();
 $("#images").show();
   }

  });
```